# How do I translate the Simpson's quote "I know, he's grooming me"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, terminology

> [image: Homer with a bird on his head]
>
> *Marge*: Oh Homer, there's a bird on your head.
> *Homer*: I know, **he's grooming me**.

In this funny quote from *The Simpsons* ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liIxeAdYvMU); episode *Bart Gets an Elephant*), I'm not quite sure how to translate the second sentence.  [*Grooming*](https://www.reed.edu/biology/professors/srenn/pages/teaching/web_2008/dklj_site_final/home.html) in this context...

> ...refers to behaviors involved in cleaning and maintaining body function and hygiene.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/?sl=en&tl=zh-CN&text=Marge%3A%20Oh%20Homer%2C%20there%27s%20a%20bird%20on%20your%20head.%0AHomer%3A%20I%20know%2C%20he%27s%20grooming%20me.%0A&op=translate) gives:

> *玛吉*：荷马，你头上有一只鸟。
> *荷马*：我知道，**他在修饰我**。

This seems plausible, but I'm unsure about how "grooming" is translated; 修饰 seems more like "decorate".  I didn't find Chinese subtitles [here](https://www.themoviedb.org/tv/456-the-simpsons/season/5/episode/17/translations#zh-CN).

**Question**: How do I translate the Simpson's quote "I know, he's grooming me"?

Answer (score 2):

For what monkeys and birds do for each other we would call it:

> 梳毛
> shū máo

梳毛 can be broken down into: brush + fur.

It normally wouldn’t work for humans, since people do not have fur but since it is an animal doing the action we can still attribute animal behaviors to the bird.

You might go with something like:
它给我梳毛

Comment: Two more choices.   1 它在给我梳头。  2 它在给我整理发型。

Answer (score 1):

玛吉：荷马，你头上有一只鸟。

荷马：我知道，他在**打扮**(**修飾/梳理**)我。